# Deleted cron lock files makes the magento unresponsive

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, cron, crontab

We truncated the table `core_url_rewrite` and deleted the files in `var/locks/*`. What happened next is our server keeps using high CPU usage. See the high CPU usage below:

[image]

I restarted apache and it keeps coming back.I don't have any idea what's happening right now.

**EDIT**

Every year we cleaned up data by creating new website instance and we keep the old instance. Each user has a unique associated product and we have thousands of users on every year/website.

I already reindex all indexes, down the site and wait to complete the indexes. It was completed around 40 minutes because it recreates all `core_url_rewrite`. I was thinking that it was completed successfully, but this high CPU usage keeps coming back.

Comment: I think some of your cron using high memory because of some logic that create issue

Comment: I'm not sure, it used to work just fine before I performed above. I disabled cronjob and it keeps executing and uses CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, magento default cronjob alone causes an issue. We had this kind of issue before and we get rid it by installing https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler